# Angular $watch variable name with underscore or camel case doesn't get updated

Tags: angularjs, watch

When I $watch a variable with underscore or camel case in its name, the $watch doesn't trigger. If the variable name being $watch'ed does not contain any underscore or camel case, it works. I don't find anything talking about the variable name being $watch'ed in Angular documentations.

Here's the code that the $watch failed to trigger:
http://jsbin.com/potiferixu/1/edit?html,console,output

Here's the code that the $watch got triggered correctly:
http://jsbin.com/sulugukaka/2/edit?html,console,output

The only difference is the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AngularJS, when you refer to variables with underscores inside a directive, you have to use the camelcase version.

Taken from the official [documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

So, you should use this in the scope:

```
scope: {
  fieldWithUnderscore: '='
},
```

and this inside the `$watch`:

```
console.log(scope.fieldWithUnderscore);
```

And (as you pointed out) also to change this:

```
scope.$watch('fieldWithUnderscore'
```

**Updated version**: http://jsbin.com/zoqupizuvi/2/edit

Comment: Thanks @thebelowcode, You answered my question. Would you change the $watch from field_with_underscore to fieldWithUnderscore as well?

Comment: It's a convention, I wouldn't rename it because I'd like to respect AngularJS conventions. But it can be obnoxious to remember the first times, and cause troubles

Comment: The thing is if you leave the line like `scope.$watch('field_with_underscore', function() {`, when you click the change button, the $watch does not get triggered. It is triggered if the line is changed to `scope.$watch('fieldWithUnderscore', function() {` in your example: http://jsbin.com/zuhofajesa/2/edit

Comment: My fault, I mistakenly forgot about it